# Disable input-group-addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to disable a datepicker when a checkbox is checked. But I can't disable the input-group-addon. Even if the text input is disabled, the user can click on the span and choose a date.

How can I disable it ?

[image: Image of the inputs, I'd like to disable the "du" and "au"]

Here's my html code :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="deb">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Du</div>
            <input id="dateDebut" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="end">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Au</div>
            <input id="dateFin" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 checkbox">
    <label> <input id='toutVisu' type="checkbox">Visu</label> 
</div>
```

And here's my js code :

```
$('input#toutVisu').on('change', function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("div.date input").prop("disabled",true)
        $("div.date input").val("")

        msg = $('#messToutVisu').val()
        msgAlert = afficheAlert("danger",msg)
        $("div#histoRapport").append(msgAlert)
        deleteAlert()
    }else{
        $("div.date input").prop("disabled",false)
    }
})
```

I tried a lot of things to disable this input but nothing worked. So I let what was already made.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('input#toutVisu').on('change', function(e) {

  var isDisabled = $(this).is(':checked');
  $("#toDisable").prop("disabled", isDisabled)
  if(isDisabled){
    $('#end, #deb').datepicker('remove');
  }else{
    $('#end, #deb').datepicker();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<fieldset id="toDisable">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="deb">
        <div class="input-group-addon">Du</div>
        <input id="dateDebut" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="end">
        <div class="input-group-addon">Au</div>
        <input id="dateFin" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="col-md-3 checkbox">
  <label> <input id='toutVisu' type="checkbox">Visu</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me I just tested on the wrong version of my site for this example and I retried. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

[`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

```js
$('input#toutVisu').on('change', function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("div.date input").prop("disabled",true)
        $("div.date input").val("")
        $(".input-group-addon").unbind('click');
        msg = $('#messToutVisu').val()
        msgAlert = afficheAlert("danger",msg)
        $("div#histoRapport").append(msgAlert)
        deleteAlert()
    }else{
        $("div.date input").prop("disabled",false)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="deb">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Du</div>
            <input id="dateDebut" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="end">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Au</div>
            <input id="dateFin" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 checkbox">
    <label> <input id='toutVisu' type="checkbox">Visu</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your answer. I tried this code and it doesn't work for me, it's always clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the event onchange might not work because change has to happen for onchange to fire.Try attaching an event on mousedown and touchend and call `event.preventDefault()` + `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` within them if the check box is checked.

Alternatively you can use the `focusin` event as well which fires before `change`

## PS

based on what you post, I cannot see those spans, but a**ssuming that they are the previousElementSibling of the input** (you can simplify the below more but I write for a quick test for you):

```
$("div.date input").prev()
.on("touchend",function(e){
    if($('input#toutVisu').is(':checked')){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
}).on("mousedown",function(e){
   if($('input#toutVisu').is(':checked')){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
   }
}).on("click",function(e){
   if($('input#toutVisu').is(':checked')){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
   }
})
```

Add the above **before** you add any custom event handlers to these elements. YOu might need to call the above on touchstart but then chrome will complain that the event is passive, so you need to set it up before hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ibowankenobi but I don't really understand the link, I'm a beginner and I've never used an event on mousedown or touchend. 
Can you explain please ?

Comment: It will be much easier for me if you make a fiddle. because the spans and the js that controls their behavior is not included in your snippet.

Comment: Try my PS and let me know if that works. otherwise a fiddle is needed

Comment: I just tried your code and it doesn't work either... I don't understand why it's so hard to disable it. It disables the input text where we can write the date but we always can click on the left button to choose a date.

Comment: It is not hard at all. What is hard is guessing what might is going on without having a reproducible live sample to start with. Everything will be much easier if you can make a minimal fiddle so we can all get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Ok I'm going to do that (first time).

Comment: Great, btw I also forget to put the "e" as the first argument to mousedown and click, I updated the code snippet. Try it again before you set  up your fiddle maybe it will work

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work. I'm making the fiddle but I have difficulties to make it work. They're a lot of files to import and I don't know all of them ^^

Comment: You are  mentioning "span" in your example. Where is the span? Is there another script that is dynamically adding elements to some classes? In that case you should add the code snippet to those "spans" instead AND before that script attaches his own handlers. This is why a fiddle is usually useful:)

Comment: Something like $("div.date input").prev("span") perhaps

Comment: No it was just a mistake from me, I don't have something like that. I made the jsfiddle but the calendar doesn't work so the left input neither.. Here's the link but I can't make it work.. https://jsfiddle.net/gbm9us7b/2/

Comment: It's ok the answer of Dementic works, I just tested his code on a wrong version of my site, but thank you very much for the time you spent to help me :)